# Electron19: unable to load preload script

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am using `electron@19` and I'm having an issue after building the application and trying to run it. Seems like my renderer process has issues. I'm not sure how to fix is as I migrated this code from electron 7 (!!!!)

Error is: `[process.on_unhandledRejection] at  {} reason: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initialize') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initialize')`

I'm not sure I'm using electron as needed.

This is my main windows script:

```
import path from 'path';

import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
import ElectronRemoteMain from '@electron/remote/main';

import config, { calculateWindowSize } from '../config';
import { forceExitApp } from './tray';
import { installExtensionsForDevelopmentAndDebug } from './extensions';
import MenuBuilder from '../modules/menu';

let mainWindow: BrowserWindow = null;

export const getMainWindow = () => mainWindow;

export async function loadWindow() {
    await installExtensionsForDevelopmentAndDebug();

    calculateWindowSize();

    ElectronRemoteMain.initialize();

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        resizable: false,
        show: false,
        width: config.main_window.width,
        maxWidth: config.main_window.width,
        minWidth: config.main_window.width,
        height: config.main_window.height,
        maxHeight: config.main_window.height,
        minHeight: config.main_window.height,
        icon: config.main_window.icon_path,
        title: config.application.title,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        fullscreenable: false,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/renderer.prod.js'),
        },
    });

    ElectronRemoteMain.enable(mainWindow.webContents);

    if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
        app.dock.setIcon(config.main_window.icon_path);

        mainWindow.setTitle(config.application.title);
    }

    mainWindow.loadURL(config.app_file_path);
    const menuBuilder = new MenuBuilder(mainWindow);
    menuBuilder.buildMenu();

    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', async () => {
        if (!mainWindow) {
            throw new Error('"mainWindow" is not defined');
        }
        if (process.env.START_MINIMIZED) {
            mainWindow.minimize();
        }
    });

    const minimizeWindow = () => {
        mainWindow.hide();
    };

    mainWindow.on('close', async () => {
        if (forceExitApp) {
            return;
        }

        if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
            mainWindow.hide();
        } else {
            mainWindow.minimize();
        }
    });

    mainWindow.on('minimize', minimizeWindow);
}
```

I can't render the electron application please advice?

Comment: hm, and you're sure `@electron/remote` is installed? What if you reinstall your modules?

Comment: does using `require` in your method help at all?  `require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()`

Comment: @SeydouDoumbia Electron has changed a lot since version 7, I'd recommend you read up a bit on some material I posted to get you up to speed. https://www.debugandrelease.com/the-ultimate-electron-guide/.

Additionally, it would be helpful to see your preload & view file to see what might be going on.

Comment: @pushkin no, it didn't help

Comment: Do you have the option to stop using `@electron/remote` and instead implement functionality via [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)?